# issue with pdf downloading " The file is damaged could not be repaired"

Tags: c#, google-chrome, pdf

I have created C# application that opens pdf in browser. once I click on download button on chrome that pdf downloads.But when I open that pdf in adobe reader 10 it shows pdf is damaged could not be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something with IO Stream , do you close the stream correctly? We need more information to give detailed answers.

Comment: Hello Jelman, Yes the stream is closed. Please help me what type of other information that I can provide you?

Comment: you could start posting relevant code snippets, now nobody knows where you're talking about.